# Difference between SpatialPolygonsDataFrame returned by readOGR on a shapefile and one created over Polygon class data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have a list of class Polygons say sdp

```
centroids  <- coordinates(SP)
x  <- centroids[,1]
y  <- centroids[,2]
z <- 1.4 + 0.1*x + 0.2*y + 0.002*x*x
SP1  <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z, value = 100*wardDensity$penetration, row.names = row.names(SP)))
```

SP1 is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, is it any different from the one created using readOGR on a shape file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: apart from your shapefile having different polygons & data, no. to prove it, you can write out this `SP` to a shapefile and read it back in with `readOGR`.

Comment: I asked the question because I was using SP1 in a ggplot with geom_polygon(aes(fill = value)), this is  returning an error:  Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14710): x, y, group, colour.

Thanks for your input

Comment: Then that's what you should have put in the question. We have no idea what your ggplot code looks like. And, if you do paste in some ggplot code we still can't fully help you if you don't make the question reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of readOGR on the rdocumentation :

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgdal/versions/1.4-3/topics/readOGR

`readOGR` import SpatialPolygonsDataFrame if you have polygone. SpatialLinesDataFrame if you have lines and points if not. It is what we can check with the following code for polygons :

```
library(GISTools)
library(rgdal) # for readOGR
library(raster) # for shapefile function
```

We create a polygon spatial object like in :

https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/202536_7a122ff56e9f4062b6b012d9921afd80.html

```
x_coord <- c(16.48438,  17.49512,  24.74609, 22.59277, 16.48438)
y_coord <- c(59.736328125, 55.1220703125, 55.0341796875, 61.142578125, 59.736328125)
xym <- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)

p = Polygon(xym)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))

class(sps)
```

We have a SpatialPolygon which is different from a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, we can export it as a shape file :

```
shapefile(sps, filename = 'sps')
```

When, we import it using `readOGR` in our current directory, we obtain a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object :

```
sps_import <- readOGR("sps")
class(sps_import)
```

In the same spirit, we can export the SP1 object and re-import it using `readOGR`, we see that we have the same type of object.

```
centroids  <- coordinates(sps)
x  <- centroids[,1]
y  <- centroids[,2]
z <- 1.4 + 0.1*x + 0.2*y + 0.002*x*x
SP1  <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sps,
                                 data = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z,
                                                   row.names = row.names(sps)))
plot(sps)
points(centroids)

writeOGR(obj=SP1, dsn="tempdir", layer="SP1", driver="ESRI Shapefile") # this is in geographical projection
import <- readOGR("tempdir/SP1.shp")

class(import)
class(SP1)
```